# Android: how to add something to end of all url using Retrofit?

Tags: android, timestamp, retrofit2

I use retrofit for webservice. I want to add Timestamp to all request url. can I do like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL + Constants.TimeStamp + System.currentTimeMillis() + Constants.Slash)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user, @Query("timestamp") long timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is that you should use like as below.if you want to  check this link [enter link description here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-adding-customizing-the-gson-converter)

```
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat(Constants.TimeStamp + System.currentTimeMillis() + Constants.Slash)
            .create();

       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
         .registerTypeAdapter(Id.class, new IdTypeAdapter())
         .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
         .serializeNulls()
         .setDateFormat(Constants.TimeStamp + System.currentTimeMillis() + Constants.Slash)
         .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
         .setPrettyPrinting()
         .setVersion(1.0)
         .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
     .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
     .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation will add the same initial timestamp to all requests performed by the retrofit instance. Is this what you desire?

If you want the current/latest timestamp as part of the url's path in each call, use an interceptor:

```
 val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor( object : Interceptor {
                override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                    val originalRequest = chain.request()
                    val originalHttpUrl = originalRequest.url()

                    val timestampUrl = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                            .addPathSegment(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
                            .build()

                    val requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                            .url(timestampUrl)
                    return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
                }
            })
            .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
```

If you want to pass the timestamp as a query parameter, like Yevhenii suggested, replace the interceptor with something like:

```
            object : Interceptor {
                override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                    val originalRequest = chain.request()
                    val originalHttpUrl = originalRequest.url()

                    val timestampUrl = originalHttpUrl.newBuilder()
                            .addQueryParameter("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
                            .build()

                    val requestBuilder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                            .url(timestampUrl)
                    return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
                }
            }
```